Flutter sqflite database location on desktop
How to change database file name to a custom path like your project folder in Flutter using Sqflite package on desktop?
When the following code is run in class named DatabaseHelper:
  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    // Initialize sqflite as sqflite_common_ffi if you are on desktop
    dev.log(" In DatabaseHelper:\n    _initDatabase(): open database.");
    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      dev.log("     On desktop.");
      sqfliteFfiInit();
    }else{
      dev.log("     On mobile.");
    }
    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    final databasePath = await databaseFactory.getDatabasesPath();
    print("Databese path: ======> $databasePath");

    final path = p.join(databasePath, SqlExp.fileName);

    return await databaseFactory.openDatabase(
      path,
      options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        version: SqlExp.version,
        onCreate: _onCreate,
      ),
    );
  }

The output is:
[log]   In  DatabaseHelper:
[log]       _initDatabase(): open database.
[log]         On desktop.
flutter: Databese path: ======> /home/(pc-hostname)/Flutter/projects/(projectName)/.dart_tool/sqflite_common_ffi/databases

But the result that is requested is same think like:
/home/(pc-hostname)/Flutter/projects/(projectName)/.databases/customPath
The getDatabasesPath() doesn't let you do that. Is there a function in Flutter or better in Dart (no external package if possible) that lets you get the current working directory, and if there is such a function, is it ok or more optimal to work with in the long run instead of the getDatabasesPath() function that came with the Sqflite package that is supposed to work well to gather, or am I mistaken?
I try getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from path_provider package but, I'm expecting a custom path directory in to my project folder, I don't want the user get access to the database that easily.

You can use Dart's Directory class to get the current working directory.
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._init();
  static Database? _database;

  DatabaseHelper._init();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    dev.log(" In DatabaseHelper:\n    _initDatabase(): open database.");
    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      dev.log("     On desktop.");
      sqfliteFfiInit();
    } else {
      dev.log("     On mobile.");
    }

    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;

    // Get the current working directory
    final currentDir = Directory.current.path;
    dev.log("Current working directory: $currentDir");

    // Define your custom path
    final customPath = p.join(currentDir, '.databases', 'customPath');
    dev.log("Custom database path: $customPath");

    // Ensure the directory exists
    final customDir = Directory(customPath);
    if (!await customDir.exists()) {
      await customDir.create(recursive: true);
    }

    final path = p.join(customPath, SqlExp.fileName);

    return await databaseFactory.openDatabase(
      path,
      options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        version: SqlExp.version,
        onCreate: _onCreate,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    // Your database creation logic here
  }
}

